# How to convert String to Number only when String including just number element

Tags: ruby

In ruby `nil.to_f` and `"".to_f` return `0.0`, and `"1foo2".to_f` returns `1.0`. In these cases I want to get `nil`.

What I want are:

```
nil.my_to_f #=> nil
"".my_to_f #=> nil
"1foo2".my_to_f #=> nil
"3".my_to_f #=> 3.0
"3.5".my_to_f #=> 3.5

'.3'.my_to_f #=> nil
'.'.my_to_f #=> nil
```

To enable this function I wrote like this:

```
match(/^([\d\.]+)$/){ $1.to_f if $1 }
```

It works fine for first five examples, but fails last two.
How can I convert String to Float like the examples?

If there is a Gem for it, I'm willing to use it.

### Update

With my code `nil` raise error, sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: why should `".3".to_f` return nil?

Comment: What should `'.'.my_to_f` return?

Comment: @Martin Is it better `.3` returns `0.3`? Then I'll follow your advice.

Comment: "'.'.my_to_f" should return `nil`. Is it strange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `Float` class for this. Beware it raises `ArgumentError` in case of wrong value:

```
def my_to_f(n)
  Float(n)
rescue
  0.0 if n == "."
end

my_to_f nil     #=> nil
my_to_f ""      #=> nil
my_to_f "1foo2" #=> nil
my_to_f "3"     #=> 3.0
my_to_f "3.5"   #=> 3.5
my_to_f ".3"    #=> 0.3
my_to_f "."     #=> 0.0
```

Comment: Actually, the OP wants `'.'.my_to_f` to return `nil`. (See the comment `ironside` added.) That was initially my understanding as well. Good use of `Float`. The OP wanted `my_to_f` defined on the `String` class, but that's a minor change.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. Actually requirement from OP is not very clear. `my_to_f(n)` function is more general and could be used with `String`, `Fixnum`, `TrueClass`, `FalseClass`, `NilClass` and other objects. If we define `my_to_f` on `String` we also need to define it on other classes as well (`NilClass` for example, as you did). So i am going to leave it as is to show approach in general.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
class NilClass
  def my_to_f
    nil
  end
end

class String
  def my_to_f
    r = /
        ^          # match beginning of string 
        -?         # optionally match minus sign      
        \d+        # match > 0 digits     
        (?:\.\d*)? # optionally match decimal, >= 0 digits in non-capture group
        $          # match end of string
        /x
    s = self[r]
    s ? s.to_f : nil
  end
end

nil.my_to_f      #=> nil
"".my_to_f       #=> nil
"1foo2".my_to_f  #=> nil
"3".my_to_f      #=> 3.0
"3.5".my_to_f    #=> 3.5
".3".my_to_f     #=> nil
".".my_to_f      #=> nil
"3.".my_to_f     #=> 3.0
"-2.4". my_to_f  #=>-2.4
```

If you want `"3.".my_to_f` to return `nil`, change `\d*` to `\d+`.

Comment: Doesn't look like this will handle negative numbers

Comment: @CarySwoveland you wrote that you assume that "." returns "0.0", but in output sample  it returns `nil`

Comment: @veelenga, thanks for noting that. (Just took that out) It was an artefact from when I understood that to be the case. After that was clarified I fixed my regex but forgot to remove that text.